# Are there standalone emulators of Applesoft Basic?

Tags: apple-ii, emulation, applesoft-basic

My only retrocomputing desire is to program in Applesoft Basic and relive the Apple II days from the 1980's.  Playing games is of no particular interest to me.  I just want to use a keyboard, not a game controller.

I really like the "Applesoft BASIC in Javascript" app at https://inexorabletash.github.io/jsbasic/ but I would like to find a stand alone program that I can download and run on a Raspberry Pi or run on a Windows machine.  I want to have a personal copy of the program.  I don't want to be dependent on someone else's web site which could possible disappear one day.  **Is such a standalone emulator available?**

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to *Retrocomputing!*  I am going to edit your question, to make the actual question stand out and improve its acceptance on this site.  If you don't like the edit, you are free to roll it back.

Comment: What hinders you to download that page and store it locally? Javascript should run from a local ressource, too.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/inexorabletash/jsbasic.git is the files on the webserver for the link you gave.  You should be able to put them on your own webserver and play as much as you want.  Note that this is not the real deal but quite close.  For the absolutely correct version you should run an Apple II emulator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there are at least a couple:

- [LinApple](https://github.com/linappleii/linapple) - for Linux/Raspberry Pi. This fork of LinApple is current and maintained, and fixes annoying configuration bugs that others hadn't addressed.
- [AppleWin](https://github.com/AppleWin/AppleWin) — for Windows.

Further to [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen's comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14363/are-there-standalone-emulators-of-applesoft-basic/14364#comment47466_14363), I can confirm that *Applesoft BASIC in JavaScript* runs quite happily from a standalone local installation if you do something like:

```
git clone https://github.com/inexorabletash/jsbasic.git
cd jsbasic
busybox httpd -f -p 8000
```

then open http://localhost:8000/ in your browser. Substitute your [favourite static server one-liner](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255) — `python3 -m http.server 8000` is a solid alternative — for the `busybox` call.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for Apple II emulators, most are cross-platform. I won't list them all, but there are more than a couple:

- [AppleWin NTSC](http://wsxyz.net/applewin.html) — runs on Linux (using Wine) and Windows.
- [Apple2ix](http://deadc0de.org/apple2ix/) — runs on Linux/Raspberry Pi.
- [microM8](https://paleotronic.com/software/microm8/) — runs on Linux/Raspberry Pi and Windows.
- [JACE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/java-ace/) — runs on anything that runs Java.
- [Epple-II](https://cmosher01.github.io/Epple-II/) — runs on Linux/Raspberry Pi and Windows.
- [MoDapple](http://modapple.buric.co/) — runs on Windows.
- [EMU][ - p.k.a. Dapple ][](http://dapple.sourceforge.net/) — runs on Linux/Raspberry Pi.
- [LinApple](http://linapple.sourceforge.net/) — runs on Linux/Raspberry Pi.
- [KEGS](http://kegs.sourceforge.net/) — runs on Linux/Raspberry Pi and Windows.
- [KEGS-SDL](http://devernay.free.fr/apple2/) — runs on Linux/Raspberry Pi and Windows.
- [GSport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gsport/) — cross-platform
- [GSplus](https://apple2.gs/plus/) — runs on Linux/Raspberry Pi and Windows.
- [XGS 32](https://www.zophar.net/apple2/xgs-32-xgs-dos.html) — runs on Windows.
- [Virtu](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=virtu) — runs on Silverlight which runs on Windows.
- [YAE](http://www.netfront.net:6502/) — runs on Linux/Raspberry Pi.

There is also a way of [Using MAME to Emulate the Apple II+](https://glasstty.com/wiki/index.php/Using_MAME_to_Emulate_the_Apple_II%2B).

Comment: AppleWin's home is https://github.com/AppleWin/AppleWin . KEGS is no longer under development; GSport and GSplus took the KEGS sources and continued on.

Comment: Good list! Note that the LinApple you link to has some very annoying bugs, including an ability to eat the user's config file. Wine apps really only work well on x86(_64) Linux: they're very poor on other CPUs. KEGS/GSport/GS+ are IIgs emulators: you can get to AppleSoft BASIC if you must, but they're a little more involved.